# Summarize objects of array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an order array. I don't see how could I summarize the orders with price and quantity. I wanted to get the prices and quantity from item object and summing it, but how could do that?

```
{
  "orders" : [ null, {
    "date" : "2018-07-09 10:07:18",
    "item" : [ {
      "name" : "Warmer Topfenstrudel",
      "price" : 3.9,
      "quantity" : 1
    } ]
  }, {
    "date" : "2018-07-09 10:07:30",
    "item" : [ {
      "name" : "Warmer Topfenstrudel",
      "price" : 3.9,
      "quantity" : 1
    } ]
  }, {
    "date" : "2018-07-09 15:07:18",
    "item" : [ {
      "name" : "Piccata Milanese",
      "price" : 12.9,
      "quantity" : 3
    } ]
  }, {
    "date" : "2018-06-13 10:07:18",
    "item" : [ {
      "name" : "Wiener Schnitzel vom Schwein",
      "price" : 9.9,
      "quantity" : 2
    } ]
  } ]
}
```

I tried following function:

```
getTotal: function(arr) {
    return arr.reduce((sum, i) => {
      return sum + (i.price * i.quantity)
    },0)
  },
```

Comment: What do you want the resulting array to look like? What have you tried so far?

Comment: What are you passing into `getTotal()` as `arr`? Each `item` is an array

Comment: The item arrays.

Comment: you should include the result you want to get. I'm having an issue interpreting your need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wanted to get the prices and quantity from item object and summing it, but how could do that?

One of the ways to do that:

```js
var j = {
  "orders": [null, {
    "date": "2018-07-09 10:07:18",
    "item": [{
      "name": "Warmer Topfenstrudel",
      "price": 3.9,
      "quantity": 1
    }]
  }, {
    "date": "2018-07-09 10:07:30",
    "item": [{
      "name": "Warmer Topfenstrudel",
      "price": 3.9,
      "quantity": 1
    }]
  }, {
    "date": "2018-07-09 15:07:18",
    "item": [{
      "name": "Piccata Milanese",
      "price": 12.9,
      "quantity": 3
    }]
  }, {
    "date": "2018-06-13 10:07:18",
    "item": [{
      "name": "Wiener Schnitzel vom Schwein",
      "price": 9.9,
      "quantity": 2
    }]
  }]
}
var ar = j.orders,
  sum = 0;
// iterates over the object array keys 
Object.keys(ar).forEach(function(i) {
  // Summing up the price * quantity
  sum += ar[i] === null ? 0 : (ar[i].item[0].price * ar[i].item[0].quantity)
  console.log(sum);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you need to sum up the `item` array for each `orders` element before you can sum across all orders

```
getTotal: function(arr) {
    return arr.reduce((sum, order) => {
      return sum + order.items.reduce((itemSum, item) => (
        itemSum + (item.price * item.quantity)
      ), 0)
    },0)
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

`item` is an array, so you need to use `reduce` on that as well, or use the first element of the array if you know that there will only be one item.

You also need have a check if the element in the array is an actual order, since you have `null` in your array.

```js
var obj = {
  orders: [
    null,
    {
      date: "2018-07-09 10:07:18",
      item: [
        {
          name: "Warmer Topfenstrudel",
          price: 3.9,
          quantity: 1
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      date: "2018-07-09 10:07:30",
      item: [
        {
          name: "Warmer Topfenstrudel",
          price: 3.9,
          quantity: 1
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      date: "2018-07-09 15:07:18",
      item: [
        {
          name: "Piccata Milanese",
          price: 12.9,
          quantity: 3
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      date: "2018-06-13 10:07:18",
      item: [
        {
          name: "Wiener Schnitzel vom Schwein",
          price: 9.9,
          quantity: 2
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

var result = obj.orders.reduce((result, order) => {
  return !order
    ? result
    : result + order.item.reduce((cost, item) => {
        return cost + item.price * item.quantity;
      }, 0);
}, 0);

console.log(result);
```